# Button should open new ContentControl based on MVVM pattern in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I wanted to create a project based on the MVVM pattern. 
Unfortunately, I didn't quite get it right and now I have numerous subsequent errors.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
        xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyProject.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="571.4" Width="730">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="Window1ViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:Window1ViewModel}">
            <views:Window1View DataContext="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        // Grid Definition not included - not relevant
        <DockPanel Background="Blue" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3">
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="Window1" 
                        Height="45"
                        Click="Window1_click"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>

        <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="4" Content="{Binding}"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Window1_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContext = new Window1ViewModel();
        }

    }
}
```

I have a window which I named Window1. This one is not quite relevant I guess.

Now the Click Event button opens the window correctly. But this does not fit the MVVM pattern. 
This will start a new thread, which then leads to countless subsequent errors.

How can I adjust the button event so that the binding is correct again.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions for you.

- Create a `MainViewModel` class, and set the `DataContext` of `MainWindow` to an instance of this.
- If possible, don't use event handlers in MVVM, especially not for button click events. Instead, in MainViewModel, create a property of type `ICommand`, and bind the button's `Command` property to it.

Depending on what (library) you're using to implement the MVVM pattern, you may already have an `ICommand` implementation, such as `MVVMLight's` `RelayCommand`. If not, you can use a basic ICommand implementation such as

```
public class BasicCommand: ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _execute;

    public Command(Action execute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute?.Invoke();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

- In MainViewModel, create a property of type object ContentViewModel, and bind the ContenControl's Content property to it. This property should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as you're going to update it from within the ViewModel.
- In the corresponding method for the command, set the ContentViewModel property to an appropriate value - e.g. a Window1ViewModel instance.
- In the ContentControl resources, define a DataTemplate for each type you might want to display. This needs to be based on a something other than a Window - eg Grid or CustomControl or UserControl.

.

```
 <ContentControl
    Margin="8"
    Content="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Window1ViewModel}">
            <ctrl:Window1Display DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Window2ViewModel}">
            <ctrl:Window2Display DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>

        ...

    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

More details, and a working example on my [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/mvvm-bringing-it-all-together/).

Comment: Thank you for your blog post. It is very useful and very good. But can you help me with the buttons? How does this work with the ContentControl